# Game trees and data structures to implement them in java?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am getting really confused with this concept:

If I want to implement a game in java, say tic tac toe using a game tree, does this mean that I have to use a tree data structure? I finished listening to one of the lectures of UCBerkley and the professor there stated that "a game tree does not mean a tree data structure implementation", but I am not sure if I am getting it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **In game theory, a game tree is a directed graph whose nodes are
>   positions in a game and whose edges are moves.** The complete game tree
>   for a game is the game tree starting at the initial position and
>   containing all possible moves from each position; the complete tree is
>   the same tree as that obtained from the extensive-form game
>   representation.

emphasis mine, [From wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_tree)

So they are really getting into details here, a graph is not necessarily a tree, but could be.

To put it another way

> a tree is an undirected graph in which any two vertices are connected
>   by exactly one simple path. In other words, any connected graph
>   without cycles is a tree.

[again from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29).

At least that is what I am getting from your question.

Comment: So if I got this right, a directed graph should be used to implement the game in java?

Comment: look at the trees wikipedia link, and read the second paragraph.  I think the distinction is between graph, tree (graph theory definition), and tree (data structure).  All are linked at some level.